# Python Regex - How to remove text between 2 characters

Tags: python, regex

How can I remove anything between `")"` and `"|"`

For example,

```
str = "left)garbage|right"
```

I need the output to be `"left)|right"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "left)garbage|right"
>>> re.sub(r'(?<=\)).*?(?=\|)', '', s)
'left)|right'

>>> re.sub(r'\).*?\|', r')|', s)
'left)|right'
```

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case, it is

```
str[:str.index(')')+1] + str[str.index('|'):]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re
>>> str = 'left)garbage|right'
>>> re.sub(r"\).*?\|",")|",str)
'left)|right'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
import re
str = "left)garbage|right"
re.sub(r"(?<=\)).*?(?=\|)", "", str)
```