# How to get all the string after and before two specific words?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to replace all the string after "my;encoded;image:" (which is the base64 data of the image) and i want to stop before the word "END" , but the following code is replacing also the two strings "my;encoded;image:" and "END". Any suggestions?

```
import re
re.sub("my;encoded;image:.*END","random_words",image,flags=re.DOTALL)
```

NB : a simple way could be to use replacement but i want to use regex in my case Thanks

Comment: Use groups: `re.sub("(my;encoded;image:).*(END)","random_words","\1"+image+"\2",...` Or just add the text to the replacement: `"my;encoded;image:" + image + "END"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Regex - How to remove text between 2 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17848520/python-regex-how-to-remove-text-between-2-characters)

Comment: Hello , no it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a non-greedy regex to split the string into three groups. Then replace the second group with your string:

```
import re

x = re.sub(r'(.*my;encoded;image:)(.*?)(END.*)', r"\1my string\3", image)

print(x)
```

You can use f-strings with Python 3.6 and higher:

```
replacement = "hello"
x = re.sub(r'(.*my;encoded;image:)(.*?)(END.*)', fr'\1{replacement}\3', image)
```